# POST datetimes with AJAX to controller asp.net core

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

im trying to get values from datepicker and post these values to controller. But these values are always null at controller side. i have read other threads regarding this issue but couldnt get any help.

```
$(function GetFeed() {

$('#get_feed').click(function () {


    var fromDate = $('#from_date').val();
    var toDate = $('#to_date').val();
    var price = $('#Price').val();
    var _data = {
        'fromDate': fromDate,
        'toDate': toDate,
        'price': price
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Home/GetFeedList',
        type: 'POST',
        data: _data,
        contentType: "application/json",  
        dataType: 'json',  
        success: function (s) {

            console.log('success' + s)
        },
        error: function (e) { console.log('something went wrong!', e, fromDate, toDate) }
    });
});
```

});

And heres controller where all parameters are null:

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> GetFeedList(string fromDate, string toDate, string price)
```

Also a viewmodel

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please insert start date")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{dd-MM-yyyy}")]
    public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please insert end date")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{dd-MM-yyyy}")]
    public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }
```

Comment: Change that Ajax call to a GET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller looks like a GET function but you are using a POST in the ajax call.

Change the AJAX call to a GET method type.

If you want a POST specifically - then add `[HttpPost]` above the controller signature

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetFeedList(string fromDate, string toDate, string price)
```

Comment: Hi, yes i actually have [HttpPost] in signature and then i wont get values. But now when i changed both the signature to HttpGet and Ajax req to GET these values are not null anymore. Wonder why it didnt work with post. But thanks !

Comment: If you had a model then the post would work better - you would have a C# model with the same properties then your controller would accept that model rather than the string values.  Please mark my answer correct if it solved your problem.

Comment: If i used Model as a param in controller what shouldi use in AJAX to pass the model from view to ajax to controller?

Comment: You can create an data object the same way you are doing it now.  You could also intercept the onsubmit function of your view then grab the model data using var data = new FormData($(form)[0]);

Comment: I pass my object to controller in this way: 'vm': $('form').serialize(), now one date is null while other isnt, but both have same HTML structure. Any ideas why?